# How to insert a View as a column into a table?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a question:

My problem is about reporting. I am not a manager and I am not a DBA. But we have to make financial reports in every Quarter. While making reports we are using different tables from Db but our data size is very big and I am using only specific columns to prepare those reports. This type of reporting causes lots of problems like cost, reliability, motivation, etc. To fix that problem I have decided to create a new table that contains required columns that are using while reporting. To create a new table with those columns is inefficient and causing other costs. To solve that problem I have decided to use the View feature of Oracle. In the first step, I want to create a view from the required columns and after that, I want to create a table with those Views of columns. **I don't know "How to insert a View as a column into a table?"**

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server *and* oracle here. What are you actually using? Either way, a `VEIW` isn't a column, a `VIEW` is a virtual table defined by a `SELECT` statement. Your question *"How to insert a View as a column into a table?"* doesn't make any sense, because a `VIEW` isn't a column; nor does it belong "in" a table.

Comment: A view is a virtual table so you may be looking for insert..select from view.

Comment: In fact, lots of people who know SQL have experienced both SQL Server and Oracle this is why I tagged them. For the second situation, I had told the story because of this; Is there any way to get rid of copying cost of the columns, If by using View feature can do that, how can I do? And thanks for your comment It is helpful to think, do you have any suggestion for me to solve that problem?

Comment: *"In fact, lots of people who know SQL have experienced both SQL Server and Oracle this is why I tagged them"* But they are completely different products. If you want an answer, you need to tag the RDBMS you are using. Every different RDBMS has a different dialect for SQL, and anything that has used SQL knows this, and knows that can't answer a qusetion, with SQL, if you don't tell us what dialect you're using. Tagging more (RDBMSs) means **less** attention, not more. People won't want to answer a question where they don't know what the correct RDBMS is.

Comment: I didn't think like this, I know I need to think more professionally, regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood what you are saying. However, what does view have to do with it? It is just a stored query, it doesn't contain any data and won't make this operation any faster.

This is what you want:

```
-- create a new table
create table new_table (col1, col2, ..., coln);

-- create a view
create or replace view v_view as
  select col1, col2, ..., coln 
  from your_big_table
  where ...;

-- insert data from view to the new table
insert into new_table (col1, co2, ..., coln)
select col1, col2, ..., coln
from v_view;
```

You'd get the same result if you directly

```
insert into new_table (col1, col2, ..., coln)
select col1, col2, ..., coln
from your_big_table
where ...;
```

---

Or, even by skipping `new_table` creation by using the CTAS (Create Table As Select):

```
create new_table as
select col1, col2, ..., coln
from your_big_table
where ...;
```

---

Another option you might want to consider is using a **materialized view**. You'd

```
create materialized view mv_view as
select col1, col2, ..., coln
from your_big_table
where ...;
```

It actually contains data; you can index its columns (and make queries you'll use for reporting purposes). If it needs to be refreshed, you can schedule it (for example, to do that during night hours) or do it on demand or whenever data is committed in the original "big" table; from what you described, nightly job might be your choice.